# knockout.js Need ul li tree structure up to 3 levels

Tags: knockout.js

Please find my html code as below.

```
      <ul data-bind="foreach: globalMenuItems " style='background:red'>
        <li>
             <a class="ms-core-suiteLink-a" data-bind="attr: { href:URL }"><span data-bind="text: name"></span></a>           
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Javascript file code as below

```
    function renderTerm(term) {
    console.log(term)

    var newMenuItem = new MenuItem(term);
    if (term.term.get_isRoot() && term.children.length > 0) {
        newMenuItem.SubMenuItem.push(term)
        ElsaGlobalNavigation.GlobalNavigation.viewModel.globalMenuItems.push(newMenuItem);
        var html = '<li class="dropdown"><a href="' + term.URL + '">' + term.name + '<span class="caret"></span></a>';
    } else if (term.children.length > 0) {
        console.log(ElsaGlobalNavigation.GlobalNavigation.viewModel.globalMenuItems)
        newMenuItem.SubMenuItem.push(term);
        ElsaGlobalNavigation.GlobalNavigation.viewModel.globalMenuItems.push(newMenuItem);
        // ElsaGlobalNavigation.GlobalNavigation.viewModel.globalMenuItems.push(term);
        var html = '<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="' + term.URL + '">' + term.name + '</a>';
    } else {
        console.log(ElsaGlobalNavigation.GlobalNavigation.viewModel.globalMenuItems)
        var html = '<li><a href="' + term.URL + '">' + term.name + '</a>';
        count++;
        ElsaGlobalNavigation.GlobalNavigation.viewModel.globalMenuItems.push(newMenuItem);
    }

    if (term.children && term.children.length) {

        html += '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';

        for (var i = 0; i < term.children.length; i++) {
            html += renderTerm(term.children[i]);
        }

        html += '</ul>';
    }

    return html + '</li>';
}
```

Currently, code displaying all li under single ul , I want ul li tree structure. As you can see image, I want knock out js section look like left side html ul li tree stucture image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's some missing info on how your viewmodel is laid out, so I recreated a very basic 3-level list in knockout, using an array `items` that could also have a further list of items within `item.children`.

I hope it helps to figure out how you can include it in this specific implementation:

```js
var viewModel = {
  items: [
    {
      name: "About Us"
    },
    {
      name: "Library",
      children: [
        {
          name: "Books",
          children: [
            { name: "Book1" },
            { name: "Book2" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "News"
    }
  ]
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul class="tree-depth-1" data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    <!-- depth 2 -->
    <ul class="tree-depth-2" data-bind="foreach: $data.children">
      <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <!-- depth 3 -->
        <ul class="tree-depth-3" data-bind="foreach: $data.children">
          <li>
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```